# Theorem 6.12 (e) in Baby Rudin: If $f \in \mathscr{R}\left(\alpha_1\right)$ and $f \in \mathscr{R}\left(\alpha_2\right)$, then $\ldots$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, proof-verification, definite-integrals

> If $f \in \mathscr{R}\left(\alpha_1\right)$ and $f \in \mathscr{R}\left(\alpha_2\right)$, then $f \in \mathscr{R}\left(\alpha_1 + \alpha_2 \right)$
>   and 
>   $$ \int_a^b f d\left(\alpha_1 + \alpha_2 \right) = \int_a^b f d\alpha_1 +  \int_a^b f d\alpha_2.$$

This is part of Theorem 6.12 (e) in the book *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Walter Rudin, 3rd edition.

Here is my proof:

> Let $$\alpha \colon= \alpha_1 + \alpha_2. $$
>
> As $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ are monotonically increasing functions defined on $[a, b]$, so is $\alpha$.
>
> Moreover, if $P = \left\{ \ x_0, x_1, \ldots, x_n \ \right\}$ is any partition of $[a, b]$, then 
>   $$\begin{align}
>  L(P, f, \alpha) &= \sum_{i=1}^n \left( \inf_{x_{i-1}\leq x \leq x_i } f(x) \right) \left[ \alpha \left(x_i \right) - \alpha \left( x_{i-1} \right) \right] \\
> &=  \sum_{i=1}^n \left( \inf_{x_{i-1}\leq x \leq x_i } f(x) \right) \left[ \alpha_1 \left(x_i \right) - \alpha_1 \left( x_{i-1} \right) \right] \\
> & \qquad +  \sum_{i=1}^n \left( \inf_{x_{i-1}\leq x \leq x_i } f(x) \right) \left[ \alpha_2 \left(x_i \right) - \alpha_2 \left( x_{i-1} \right) \right] \\
> &= L \left( P, f, \alpha_1 \right) + L \left( P, f, \alpha_2 \right), \tag{1}
> \end{align}
> $$
>   and similarly, 
>   $$  U (P, f, \alpha) = U \left( P, f, \alpha_1 \right) + U \left( P, f, \alpha_2 \right). \tag{2}$$
>
> Now as $f \in \mathscr{R}\left(\alpha_1\right)$ and $f \in \mathscr{R}\left(\alpha_2\right)$, so for every real number $\varepsilon > 0$ we can find partitions $P_1$ and $P_2$ of $[a, b]$ such that 
>   $$ U \left( P_1, f, \alpha_1 \right) - L \left( P_1, f, \alpha_1 \right) < { \varepsilon \over 2 } \  \mbox{ and } \  U \left( P_2, f, \alpha_2 \right) - L \left( P_2, f, \alpha_2 \right) < { \varepsilon \over 2 }. \tag{3} $$
>
> Now if $P$ is any partition of $[a, b]$ such that $P \supset P_1$ and $P \supset P_2$, then we have, for each $j = 1, 2$, 
>   $$ L \left( P_j, f, \alpha_j \right) \leq L \left( P, f, \alpha_j \right) \leq U \left( P, f, \alpha_j \right) \leq U \left( P_j, f, \alpha_j \right),$$
>   and so 
>   $$  U \left( P, f, \alpha_j \right) - L  \left( P, f, \alpha_j \right) \leq 
> U \left( P_j, f, \alpha_j \right) - L \left( P_j, f, \alpha_j \right). \tag{4} $$
>   From (3) and (4), we see that, for each $j = 1, 2$, we have 
>   $$  U \left( P, f, \alpha_j \right) - L  \left( P, f, \alpha_j \right) < { \varepsilon \over 2 }, $$
>   which together with (1) and  (2) yields 
>   $$
> \begin{align}
>  U (P, f, \alpha) - L (P, f, \alpha)  &= \left[  U \left( P, f, \alpha_1 \right) + U \left( P, f, \alpha_2 \right) \right] - \left[  L \left( P, f, \alpha_1 \right) + L \left( P, f, \alpha_2 \right) \right] \\
> &=  \left[  U \left( P, f, \alpha_1 \right) - L \left( P, f, \alpha_1 \right) \right] + \left[  U \left( P, f, \alpha_2 \right) -  L \left( P, f, \alpha_2 \right) \right] \\
> &< { \varepsilon \over 2 } + { \varepsilon \over 2 } \\
> &= \varepsilon,
> \end{align}
> $$
>   and thus it follows that $f \in \mathscr{R}\left(\alpha_1 + \alpha_2 \right)$.
>
> Finally, 
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> \int_a^b f d\alpha &= \int_a^b f d \left( \alpha_1 + \alpha_2 \right) \\
> &= \inf \left\{ \ U(P, f, \alpha) \ \colon \ \mbox{ P is a partition of } [a, b] \ \right\} \\
> &= \inf \left\{ \ U \left(P, f, \alpha_1 \right) + U \left(P, f, \alpha_2 \right)  \ \colon \ \mbox{ P is a partition of } [a, b] \ \right\} \\
> &\geq \inf \left\{ \ U \left(P, f, \alpha_1 \right) \ \colon \ \mbox{ P is a partition of } [a, b] \ \right\} + \inf \left\{ U \left(P, f, \alpha_2 \right)  \ \colon \ \mbox{ P is a partition of } [a, b] \ \right\} \\
> &= \int_a^b f d \alpha_1 + \int_a^b f d \alpha_2, \tag{5}
> \end{align} 
> $$
>   and 
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> \int_a^b f d\alpha &= \int_a^b f d \left( \alpha_1 + \alpha_2 \right) \\
> &= \sup \left\{ \ L(P, f, \alpha) \ \colon \ \mbox{ P is a partition of } [a, b] \ \right\} \\
> &= \sup \left\{ \ L \left(P, f, \alpha_1 \right) + L \left(P, f, \alpha_2 \right)  \ \colon \ \mbox{ P is a partition of } [a, b] \ \right\} \\
> &\leq \sup \left\{ \ L \left(P, f, \alpha_1 \right) \ \colon \ \mbox{ P is a partition of } [a, b] \ \right\} + \sup \left\{ L \left(P, f, \alpha_2 \right)  \ \colon \ \mbox{ P is a partition of } [a, b] \ \right\} \\
> &= \int_a^b f d \alpha_1 + \int_a^b f d \alpha_2. \tag{6}
> \end{align} 
> $$
>   From (5) and (6), we can conclude that 
>   $$ \int_a^b f d \left( \alpha_1 + \alpha_2 \right) = \int_a^b f d \alpha_1 +  \int_a^b f d \alpha_2,$$
>   as required.

Is this proof sound enough in terms of logic and rigor?